# How to remove author and affiliation superscript?

Tags: author-number, authblk, wlscirep

I am using the code below but I do not want the author and the affiliation to have that superscript symbol appearing. How do I remove it using the latex script below:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage{authblk}
\title{Report Ttile}
\author[]{John Smith}
\affil{University Name}
\affil[*]{j.smith@uni.com}
```

the current image is as below:

[image]

Comment: I think it's enough to write only this \author{John Smith} instead \author[]{John Smith}
\affil{University Name}
\affil[*]{j.smith@uni.com}

Comment: thanks, it actually worked when i removed [*] from the second affil. somehow it links to the author and university.